# Monit rails script in rvm environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, monit

I'm using some gems in rails that needs to start as daemon (crom, apn_sender) and using RVM in User-Mode for ruby-environment.

Starting and monitoring thin seems to be easy as it's possible to create a rvm wrapper for thin.

But how to start the scripts?

By hand, I would dot the following:

1. su to rubyuser
2. Switch the gemset
3. starting the script via /railsdir/script/crom start

but I don't know how to do this with monit.

Is there a way to create a wrapper for the scripts or something else?

Answer (score 0):

use wrapper for ruby, while the script is executed without ruby it will find a ruby to run it, when prefixed with ruby - it will use that ruby no matter of the shebang line in it:

```
/path/to/rvm/bin/ruby-1.9.3-p194 /railsdir/script/crom start
```